# Way to differentiate two USB devices with same product/vendor ID in retropie

Tags: usb, emulation

I am using a usb NES and usb SNES controller for emulators on retropie.  I found out both of these controllers were made by the same vendor and have the same iProduct name, IdVendor, and IdProduct values, which makes my raspberry pi see these as the same device.  Of course, now I keep overwriting config.  Is there a way to do something where I can get this USB device name changed so the system can differentiate?

Both controllers show up in lsusb as "0079x0011 DragonRise inc, Gamepad" and have Product name as "2 USB Gamepad"

Comment: If they have USB serial numbers and retropie supports identifying USB devices by serial number, then that could work.  "lsusb -v" will show you the USB descriptiors, which include the serial number if it's present.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41535538/1778421